# How to validate Ethereum addresses in PHP

Tags: php, curl, json-rpc, ethereum

I'm using PHP and curl with json to interact with my geth server.

I'm able to do all I want except one thing: checking if user's inputted address is valid according to ethereum wallet format.

I saw a javascript function [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid#1379), but I'm mostly using PHP, I'm not into JS at all.

Any ideas how to validate ethereum addresses in PHP?

Comment: Also, read the general algorithm (how is it checked generally) and write it in PHP

Comment: Can you provide any constructive answer about ethereum/regex validation in PHP or you just felt here by hazard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a PHP implementation for Ethereum address validation against the [EIP 55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md) specification. For details of how it works, please go through the comments.

```php
<?php

use kornrunner\Keccak; // composer require greensea/keccak

class EthereumValidator
{
    public function isAddress(string $address): bool
    {
        // See: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/7935e5f/lib/utils/utils.js#L415
        if ($this->matchesPattern($address)) {
            return $this->isAllSameCaps($address) ?: $this->isValidChecksum($address);
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function matchesPattern(string $address): int
    {
        return preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/i', $address);
    }

    protected function isAllSameCaps(string $address): bool
    {
        return preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $address) || preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9A-F]{40}$/', $address);
    }

    protected function isValidChecksum($address)
    {
        $address = str_replace('0x', '', $address);
        $hash = Keccak::hash(strtolower($address), 256);

        // See: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/pull/134/files#diff-db8702981afff54d3de6a913f13b7be4R42
        for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++ ) {
            if (ctype_alpha($address{$i})) {
                // Each uppercase letter should correlate with a first bit of 1 in the hash char with the same index,
                // and each lowercase letter with a 0 bit.
                $charInt = intval($hash{$i}, 16);

                if ((ctype_upper($address{$i}) && $charInt <= 7) || (ctype_lower($address{$i}) && $charInt > 7)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Dependencies

To validate checksum addresses, we need a [keccak-256](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550) implementation in place which is not supported by the built-in [`hash()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.hash.php) function. You need to require the [greensea/keccak composer package](https://github.com/greensea/php-keccak) as a dependency.

---

*Kudos to @WebSpanner for pointing out the issue with SHA3 hashing.*

Comment: I'm now using web3.js directly in my dapp. No php woth ethereum they don't go well together lol. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @sepehr This implementation is correct algorithmically, but the hashing algorithm used (sha3-256) is not correct according to the spec. The correct hashing algorithm is keccack-256, which is essentially the same hashing algorithm which differs only in a padding constant but therefore produces different results.

Replace the Sha3 class here with the Keccak class from the greensea/keccak package to get the desired result.

I've refrained from adding a new answer because I think sepehr should edit this one as I'd only be using his code except for this minor change.

Comment: Further reading:

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md
https://github.com/status-im/nim-keccak-tiny/issues/1

Comment: Sha3 generation is not correct here! Example: Address: 0xfb6916095ca1df60bb79ce92ce3ea74c37c5d359, hash: 9abe8ec2cc3d024b8cec105fd0c6da114c2b6f3413e0f080242c304024f5f7ec, I have try Node.js code for this address, it returns different hash: d5272d0fe053f9072ef335d27ac67d481da35108f4e59711486ae6cff4a16ee5

Comment: Your answer was extremely helpful, and so is [ethereum-address-validator](https://github.com/psychob/ethereum-address-validator) which can also return the canonical address.

Comment: You don't need to use regex in isAllSameCaps since the format is already checked in matchesPattern. Instead you could just test that the address is equal to the lower/upper case version of it:

``return strtolower($value) === $value || strtoupper($value) === $value;``

Comment: That makes perfect sense @ub3rst4r. Please feel free to edit the answer, if you like.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you can convert the javascript entirely to PHP.
Here i have been able to convert and test the code for validating an ethereum address in PHP.

```
/**
 * Checks if the given string is an address
 *
 * @method isAddress
 * @param {String} $address the given HEX adress
 * @return {Boolean}
*/
function isAddress($address) {
    if (!preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/i',$address)) {
        // check if it has the basic requirements of an address
        return false;
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/',$address) || preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9A-F]{40}$/',$address)) {
        // If it's all small caps or all all caps, return true
        return true;
    } else {
        // Otherwise check each case
        return isChecksumAddress($address);
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if the given string is a checksummed address
 *
 * @method isChecksumAddress
 * @param {String} $address the given HEX adress
 * @return {Boolean}
*/
function isChecksumAddress($address) {
    // Check each case
    $address = str_replace('0x','',$address);
    $addressHash = hash('sha3',strtolower($address));
    $addressArray=str_split($address);
    $addressHashArray=str_split($addressHash);

    for($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++ ) {
        // the nth letter should be uppercase if the nth digit of casemap is 1
        if ((intval($addressHashArray[$i], 16) > 7 && strtoupper($addressArray[$i]) !== $addressArray[$i]) || (intval($addressHashArray[$i], 16) <= 7 && strtolower($addressArray[$i]) !== $addressArray[$i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Meanwhile, for someone looking for a very simple regular expression for checking ethereum address validity (e.g to use is as a pattern attribute of an HTML field), this regular expression may suffice.

```
^(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$
```

Comment: Thanks ! I now use jquery and web3.js so I can use web3.isAddress() :)

Comment: Unknown hashing algorithm: sha3

Comment: Not only non-working, but also wrong implementation and yet accepted. Amazing world we live in.

Comment: @sepehr Maybe you should clarify where exactly you need help with. FYI I actually copied pasted the code above after using it myself.

Comment: @tormuto I don't think I need help, thanks :) I wonder how could you "use" the code while `hash()` has no support for SHA3 and the second set of `preg_match` calls are actually being mistakenly negated.

Comment: There is no `sha3` hashing algorythm in PHP. Use `sha3-256` instead, which is available from the PHP 7.1.0

Comment: Does not work with sha3, and it's a wrong hash with sha3-256. @sepehr's solution works...